# How to sync heights of cousin html elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have the following jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4vpnLh52/4/

Which looks like this:

```css
.myRow{
    display: table;
    overflow: auto;
}

.myGroup{
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myRow">
    <div class="myGroup">
        <div id="label1" class="myLabel myCell">
            LAbel 1:
        </div>
        <div class="myInput myCell">
            Input 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="myGroup">
        <div  id="label2" class="myLabel myCell">
            Label 22222222222222222222222:
        </div>
        <div class="myInput myCell">
            Input 22222222222222222222222
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically what I am looking for is a solution that will make the height of #label1 match #label2 (and by extension, their associated .myInput.

I know I can do this using display:table and move the labels into a separate row themselves, but these pages are made up of a bunch of different templates, and is supposed to be very modular so it is very difficult to separate the label from the input. Plus, there may be elements that do not have an associated label.

I would prefer to limit the changes to html/css changes but am open to using modern css3 as long as IE10+ is supported, including flexbox. I have looked at flexboxbut I am unsure if it can serve this purpose.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with flexbox:

- Place all the elements inside the same flex container. You can remove the `.myGroup` wrappers, or leave them and use (warning: not widely supported)

  ```css
  .myGroup {
    display: contents;
  }
  ```
- Style the flex container:

  ```css
  .myRow {
    display: flex;   /* Magic begins */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow line breaks */
    width: 120px;    /* 2 * 60px */
  }
  ```
- Style the flex items

  ```css
  .myCell {
    width: 50%; /* 60px */
  }
  ```
- Order the flex items properly:

  ```css
  .myCell:nth-child(even) {
    order: 1;
  }
  ```

This will work because, by default, [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) is `stretch`. So the flex items will be stretched to have the same height.

```css
.myRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 120px;
}
.myCell {
  width: 50%;
}
.myCell:nth-child(even) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="myRow">
  <div id="label1" class="myLabel myCell">
    Label 1:
  </div>
  <div class="myInput myCell">
    Input 1
  </div>
  <div id="label2" class="myLabel myCell">
    Label 22222222222222222222222:
  </div>
  <div class="myInput myCell">
    Input 22222222222222222222222
  </div>
</div>
```